# Looping svg rectangles from database

Tags: python, css, mysql, svg

I am reading svg rectangles from a databse using python, I don't know if this is the right way, as it seems I am hardcoding, this because I want each rectangle to change colours in my css style sheet. Is there a better way to call these rectangles rather than using ifs and elifs because if  I have 100 rectangles, what is the better way to do it. I have added my stylesheet aswell

```
for row in c: 

 box_x = ((row[3]-row[1])/2 + row[1] - 0.25)
 box_y = ((row[4]-row[2])/2 + row[2] - 0.25)
 move1 = box_y * 2
 try1 =  row[1] * 2  

 if row[0] == 1:
    print('<rect id= rectangle1 class= "rectangles" onmousemove="myFunction3()" x=',row[1],' y=',row[2],' width=',row[3]-row[1],' height=',row[4]-row[2],'><title>Owned by',row[6],'</title></rect>')
 elif row[0] == 2:
    print('<rect  id="rectangle2" class= "rectangles"   onmousemove="myFunction3()" x=',row[1],' y=',row[2],' width=',row[3]-row[1],' height=',row[4]-row[2],'><title>Owned by',row[6],'</title></rect>')
 elif row[0] == 3:
    print('<rect  id="rectangle3" class= "rectangles"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" onmousemove="myFunction3()" x=',row[1],' y=',row[2],' width=',row[3]-row[1],' height=',row[4]-row[2],'><title>Owned by',row[6],'</title></rect>')
 elif row[0] == 4:
    print('<rect id="rectangle4" class= "rectangles" onmousemove="myFunction3()" x=',row[1],' y=',row[2],' width=',row[3]-row[1],' height=',row[4]-row[2],'><title>Owned by',row[6],'</title></rect>')
 elif row[0] == 5:
    print('<rect id="rectangle5" class= "rectangles"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" onmousemove="myFunction3()" x=',row[1],' y=',row[2],' width=',row[3]-row[1],' height=',row[4]-row[2],'><title>Owned by',row[6],'</title></rect>')
 elif row[0] == 6:
    print('<rect id="rectangle6" class= "rectangles"  onmousemove="myFunction3()" x=',row[1],' y=',row[2],' width=',row[3]-row[1],' height=',row[4]-row[2],'><title>Owned by',row[6],'</title></rect>')
 elif row[0] == 7:
    print('<rect id="rectangle7" class= "rectangles"  onmousemove="myFunction3()" x=',row[1],' y=',row[2],' width=',row[3]-row[1],' height=',row[4]-row[2],'><title>Owned by',row[6],'</title></rect>')
 else:
    print('<rect id="rectangle8" class= "rectangles"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" onmousemove="myFunction3()" x=',row[1],' y=',row[2],' width=',row[3]-row[1],' height=',row[4]-row[2],'><title>Owned by',row[6],'</title></rect>')
```

css stylesheet

```
.rectangles{
        fill:       #ff3333;
        stroke:     #000000;
        stroke-width:   0.1; 

}
#rectangle1:hover{
        stroke:     #FF7F00;
        stroke-width:   0.1;
        fill:       #A52A2A;
}  
#rectangle2:hover{
        stroke:     #FF7F00;
        stroke-width:   0.1;
        fill:       #A52A2A;
}
#rectangle3:hover{
        stroke:     #FF7F00;
        stroke-width:   0.1;
        fill:       #006400;
}
#rectangle4:hover{
        stroke:     #FF7F00;
        stroke-width:   0.1;
        fill:       #000000;
}
#rectangle5:hover{
        stroke:     #FF7F00;
        stroke-width:   0.1;
        fill:       #006400;
}
#rectangle6:hover{
        stroke:     #FF7F00;
        stroke-width:   0.1;
        fill:       #000000;
}
#rectangle7:hover{
        stroke:     #FF7F00
        stroke-width:   0.1;
        fill:       #FFFFFF;
}
#rectangle8:hover{
        stroke:     #FF7F00;
        stroke-width:   0.1;
        fill:       #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Will it be a unique color for each of the rectangles on the page?

Comment: @dom_ahdigital yes, the colour changes onhover

Comment: That wasn't my question. I want to know if you will have 100 different colours or, for example 10 colours that get used multiple times.

Comment: @dom_ahdigital Yes, I will

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from you code, it looks like you should just be able to do:

```
for i, row in enumerate(c): 
    box_x = ((row[3]-row[1])/2 + row[1] - 0.25)
    box_y = ((row[4]-row[2])/2 + row[2] - 0.25)
    move1 = box_y * 2
    try1 =  row[1] * 2  

    print('<rect id="rectangle{0}" class="rectangles" x="{1}" y="{2}" width="{3}" height="{4}" onmousemove="myFunction3()"><title>Owned by {5}</title></rect>'.format(i, row[1], row[2], row[3] - row[1], row[4] - row[2], row[6]))
```